# Compute capability error when trying to compile ccminer

Tags: linux, mining-software, compiling

I am trying to compile ccminer to work with a GPU that has compute capability 3.5.

When I compile with the default nvcc_ARCH (compute capability 5.0 + 5.2), the code compiles but when I try to benchmark `./ccminer --benchmark` I get the following error:

`Cuda error in func 'quark_blake512_cpu_setBlock_80' at line 815 : invalid device symbol.`

For what I have been able to figure out, this error is related to compute capability errors, and that is why I tried changing the setting in the makefile.

I have changed Makefile.am accordingly so that nvcc_ARCH matches only the 3.5 capability (only 3.5), and I get this error:

`ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000015a2_00000000-6_cuda_x11_echo.ptx, line 10165; error   : Instruction 'lop3' requires .target sm_50 or higher`

I have also tried maintaining the original nvcc_ARCH (5.0 and 5.2) and appending the 3.5 line (+), and this is the error I get:

`ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00006277_00000000-6_cuda_x11_echo.compute_35.ptx, line 9182; error   : Instruction 'lop3' requires .target sm_50 or higher`

With all 4 lines of nvcc_ARCH uncommented, this is the error I get when compiling:

`Algo256/cuda_bmw256.cu(337): error: identifier "__ldg" is undefined`

What am I missing here? Am I trying to do this the wrong way? Is this problem not related with ccminer and I am looking at the wrong place?